# Changing default crontab editor

Tags: cron, default-programs, text-editor

I am trying to change the default editor from `nano` to `vim`.

I have run the following commands:

`sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

and

`update-alternatives --config editor`

Both now output:

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
```

I have restarted my ssh session and restarted sshd but crontab -e still opens in nano

What else do I need to do?

Comment: I don't think any of these answers actually address the question do they?

Comment: Here is a more extensive answer:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/977538/16-04-crontab-e-editor-settings-python-syntax-highlighting-in-vim

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Try your ssh session followed by

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

or possibly

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim.basic
```

The format of setting of the EDITOR variable depends on which shell you are using.

In Ubuntu you can set the EDITOR environment variable on logon by adding the above to the `~/.profile`

Your SSH session will read a similar file (if it exists) on the remote host called  `~/.ssh/environment`.  This has to be specifically defined by the ssh daemon config.  See `man sshd_config` and look for `PermitUserEnvironment` for more details.

Comment: This works in CentOS too

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to use .bashrc here? seems to work for me, or is .profile better?

Comment: The select-editor answer below is a better answer

Comment: editor is `export EDITOR="emacsclient -c"` but it keeps opening it as GUI

Answer (score 300):

Just simply run `select-editor`, this will let you choose any editor you want.

Comment: Better answer I think than what was picked.  Don't have to change my bash profile to set the editor.  Verified by logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Definitely should've been the accepted answer! This helped a lot! :D

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me

Comment: Best answer. ...

Comment: Continues to be *the* answer to go to! Thanks, @MostafaShahverdy !

Comment: what provides select-editor?

Comment: @Brunis run select-editor in console.  It's a normal shell command.

Comment: select-editor not working on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: I want to use micro but it's not on the list...

Comment: In that case, if you know the path of your editor, you can edit  `~/.selected_editor` and put something like `SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"` in it.

Comment: zsh: command not found: select-editor

Comment: Any way to use a custom editor, like Sublime Text 4?

Comment: In OpenSUSE Tumbleweed too `select-editor` does not exist and it doesn't even show up among the installable packages. It seems your only option is to set the environment variables for those cases.

Answer (score 36):

If you only want to choose the editor temporarily, you can do the following

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

If you want do this for `root` user then:

```
sudo EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

This sets the `EDITOR` environment variable for the command

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to edit the sudo/root's crontab without needing to change the root user's editor or something (on the shared VM that others might want a different editor for).

Comment: This helped me a lot too, but how to change the crontab editor permanent? I changed it as a text editor for `sudoedit`, but it still uses vim for crontab (unless I use this answer. However I would prefer not having to type `sudo EDITOR=nano` every time). And... yes, I know, many of you disagree, but I do prefer nano, sorry.

Answer (score 28):

My personal preference...

```
cd /bin
mv nano nano_must_die
ln -s /usr/bin/vim nano
```

Comment: I love it, worked out well enough for me after update-alternatives didnt work.

Comment: I wouldn't know what's wrong with nano for admins who don't see value in learning vi commands just to tweak some config files.

Comment: I guess do whatever you like on your own personal machine. But on a machine shared with anyone else, this suggestion essentially disables nano for all users in a way that when a user specifically requests nano, they get vim instead. What's the point of that? If they wanted vim, they would ask for it. If the issue here is that the system is configured to automatically invoke nano in some circumstance where you personally prefer vim, then change the configuration.

Comment: I guess this was an ironic/satiric joke for vi fans, but not everybody gets a joke, I guess.

Comment: why are you killing `nano`?

Comment: Downvote. I get that this is a joke but jokes aren't useful answers. Also, I never want to work at a place where someone would actually rename nano rather than configuring things properly.

Answer (score 17):

From "man crontab":

```
   The -e option is used to edit the  current  crontab  using  the  editor
   specified  by  the  VISUAL  or EDITOR environment variables.  After you
   exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed  automati‐
   cally.  If  neither  of  the environment variables is defined, then the
   default editor /usr/bin/editor is used.
```

Perhaps you have the EDITOR enivronment variable set to nano?

Answer (score 14):

On my Ubuntu 12.04 computer, `crontab` uses the `~/.selected_editor` file, which contains the path of the selected editor. Edit it:

```
nano ~/.selected_editor
```

I have edited it directly or used `select-editor`, which is a script to do the same thing. Edit the following line:

```
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

IHMO people should not be changing anything in /etc or /bin to do this.  It is a user level thing, not a system wide task.

Comment: for gedit: `SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/gedit"`

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem - crontab -e relies on select-editor, visudo relies on the config of "alternatives"

My solution:

run both commands as root

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/sensible-editor 50

# select-editor 

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/sensible-editor
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [1]: 3
```

Comment: As root?  Better use `sudo` (see for instance [what are the benefits of sudo over su](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su)

Answer (score 3):

I was having difficulties with `select-editor` and `update-alternatives`, my solution was to simply edit the link:

1. `sudo rm /etc/alternatives/editor`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vim /etc/alternatives/editor`

`editor` now opens Vim

Answer (score 3):

After trying the answers above, the only thing that worked for me (in Debian strech) was to remove `~/.selected_editor` by running:

```
rm ~/.selected_editor
```

And then select the new editor next time you run `crontab -e`.

Comment: This worked on my GCE linux ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to checking that the environmental variable **EDITOR** is set correctly, you should also check to make sure the variable **VISUAL** is also set correctly.

**VISUAL will override EDITOR**

From the documentation:

> The  -e  option  is  used to edit the current crontab using the
> editor specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables.

For example, if you set

```
$ export EDITOR=vim
$ export VISUAL=nano
```

Then the command `crontab -e` will still open in nano.

You should set both to be the editor of choice, ala vim for me:

```
$ export EDITOR=vim
$ export VISUAL=vim
```

Then the command `crontab -e` will open in vim.

Comment: Are there corresponding commands for exporting a variable for root (`sudo`) and possibly make the changes permanent (stay there after reboot)?