# Why are many operations or commands in Ubuntu not allowed normally when you can just do the same thing by typing sudo?

Tags: permissions, security, sudo

What purpose does this server when bypassing is as easy as typing sudo?

Forgive the naivety here but I am a rookie and I'm sure there has to be a good reason for this, and I'd like to know that.

Comment: See similar: ["Why bother with repeated `sudo` when you can just do the same thing by typing `su` once?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su)

Comment: Thanks @izx. Did not notice that before. I actually didn't even know su exists till now. New to Ubuntu.

Comment: If you are already admin (which everyone is on default Ubuntu install), then all `sudo` does is make sure you think before you do something that may be potentially dangerous if done wrong (typo, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security! ;-)

Only admin users can do sudo and even those have to provide a password, i.e. if you leave your screen for a minute, nobody can do sudo without the password.