# How do I set the root password so I can use su instead of sudo?

Tags: command-line, password, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

I'd like to define a password for root so that I can use `su` directly, without having to prepend it with `sudo`. And because I'd like to log in as root as well.

So how to set a password for the root user?

Comment: Why do you want to have a root password? You don't need it; any time you need root access, you can use `sudo`.

Comment: @Zignd: No, `sudo` requires *your* password, not the root password. Ubuntu is designed to work without a root password. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: You sometimes need root password for recovery

Comment: @KeithThompson If systemd fails it will ask for root password to enter maintenance mode:

`Welcome to emergency mode! Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): `

Comment: @cheshirekow: Hmm, I've never run into that. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.10. Looking at my `/etc/shadow`, I see that my system doesn't have a root password, and I was never prompted to create one when I set up the system. I guess if I ever get that "`Give root password for maintenance`" prompt I'll just have to press Control-D. (I haven't looked into systemd.)

Comment: @KeithThompson it's not unreasonable to want to use su to login as root if you so wish. It is after all, your environment.

Comment: @Manachi: Sure, you can do anything you like with your environment. But you can get a root shell via `sudo -i` or equivalently `sudo --login`, which doesn't require a root password. (But see the above comments regarding systemd, which I still haven't looked into.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> **Warning:** Directly logging in as *root* is like playing with fire, because one little typo is enough to **lose critical data or make your system unbootable**. Note that desktop environments will also function incorrectly if you login to them as *root.*
>
> See these questions for the reasons behind why `sudo` is preferred and why root-login is disabled by default:
>
> 1. [What are the benefits of sudo over su?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su/135429#135429)
> 2. [Why is there no option to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root)

You may have noticed that you can’t log in as root on Ubuntu, this is because root doesn’t actually have a password set.

Enter the following command:

```
sudo passwd
```

You will be prompted for your current user's password, followed by the password you want to set for root. The messages prompted should be similar to the following:

```
[sudo] password for <username>: <Type your user password and press return>
Type new UNIX password: <Type the root password you want>
Retype new UNIX password: <Retype the root password you chose in the previous prompt>
```

The following message will appear after that:

```
passwd: password updated successfully
```

If the above message showed up on your terminal, you can now enter as root from your current user entering the following command:

```
su
```

And you will be prompted for the root password you've set. That's it!

Comment: FYI, this works for RedHat Linux on vagrant as well.

Answer (score 11):

If you still want to use `su` after reading the warnings in the question, there **is no need to set a root password**. Just do `sudo su` and you're on your way with your regular password.

Comment: Or `sudo -i`, or `sudo --login`

Answer (score 7):

What I do to create the root on ubuntu:
first I do this

```
sudo -i
```

then

```
passwd
```

as @Zignd mentioned the classical messages will appear:

```
Type new UNIX password: [Type the root password you want]
Retype new UNIX password: [Retype the root password you chosen before]
passwd: password updated successfully
```

then I can use the `su` as a normal root acount...

Comment: To be simplified, `sudo -i passwd` can do the same thing.