# Re-disabling the root account

Tags: sudo, root, su, passwd

In ubuntu by default the `su` (root) password is not not set. I have set it by using the `sudo passwd` (see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155278/how-do-i-set-the-root-password-so-i-can-use-su-instead-of-sudo#)). But I didn't like it. Can I go back to my original state.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root account in Ubuntu is defaultly disabled. When you enabled the root account (set a password for it) then you can disble it easy by the following command:

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

- `-d` means to delete the password (make it empty)
- `-l` means lock the password of the account