# How can I run everything as root

Tags: lubuntu, sudo

I have dual booted to lubuntu (with Windows XP) and everytime and then I'm getting asked for my password. How do I run everything as root and not ask a password again? Ideally I wanted to run nginx but it has permission denied issues:

```
apathetic@ubuntu:~$ service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2012/08/03 20:06:25 [warn] 4762#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2012/08/03 20:06:25 [emerg] 4762#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: It's a bad idea running everything as root. It ruins security.And i don want to give bad advice. There is a very good reasons that Linux is quite secure and that services run under their own users.

Comment: You don't want to do that. There is a way to temporarily become root to run certain commands, called "sudo" for commandline programs, or "gksudo" for graphical programs. In your case, use `sudo service nginx start", which will require your password.

Comment: does a bad idea have to mean you have to downvote?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su

Comment: @Michelle Bad idea should not mean a downvote. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bad idea to run *everything* as root.

For things that actually need to be run as root (which includes `service nginx start`), the best way is to use `sudo`:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

By default, this will ask for your password if you haven't entered it in the last 15 minutes.

You can configure `/etc/sudoers` to let you run commands as root without entering your password using `NOPASSWD`. `man sudoers` for details.

(The `visudo` command is the recommended way to edit `/etc/sudoers`.)

If you insist on executing commands directly as root, you can launch a root shell with

```
sudo bash
```

or

```
 sudo -i
```

(equivalent to `sudo --login`).

My advice: Don't do this. Typing `sudo` for every command that actually needs root access helps remind you not to use it unnecessarily. It's *very* easy to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Keith is exactly right. If you have a few things you need to do at some time, and simply must save a few keystrokes, you can enter `sudo bash` and keep the shell open just to do what you need to do. The use of sudo has evolved as a "best practice" after demand from administrators and users who have made countless awful mistakes over the last few decades.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the sudo command, at the front of your command string to run something as root;

i.e. #sudo service nginx start

If you want to run as root "all the time" (not a great idea), you can set a password for the root user (sudo passwd) and then login, or su to root.

If you are just looking to run this service as root "all the time" then you can add it to /etc/rc.local and this will start the service as root at boot time?

I hope that this helps.

Comment: No need to set a password for root; `sudo bash` gives you a root shell.

Comment: Well I dont know. Ive always set a passwort for root. Eg. if your _new_ user password is lost or forgotten, or you couldnt log into your account for whatever reason you could repair this issue, when having activate the root user. Its a second chance. I dont see no obvious reason not to set root password. But I know its almost a religious discussion with good argument on both sides ;-)