# Root account at set up

Tags: password

When I set up Ubuntu (Ubuntu 10.) on my old IBM Thinkpad it asked me my name for user name I assume, and to chose a password. I did all that, now, I'm coming to Ubuntu from Mepis 11, and it's pretty similar, but the whole sudo thing, in Mepis, sudo is disabled by default, and you use su then your password the exit # right after you do what you need to do back to $

Now, my question is, I'm the only one who uses this computer, and the only user set up on here is Steve (me) with my password....when I log onto the computer, I'm wondering am I logging on as root or as just user? I don't want to log on as root, so should I set up another user account? (like you do for Windows 7 when you set it up)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su

Answer (score 1):

You're logging in as a user who has sudo rights thus being able to get root for a command.

You're **not** root. root has no password on Ubuntu and one can't log in as root by default.