# Can I start Terminator as root?

Tags: root, terminator

I am using Terminator, because it has cool ability to split itself into more terminals. But can it be run as root, without need to type `sudo -i` after launch? (adding *Run as root* into Terminator shell for example)

Comment: Just curious: why do you need a root shell?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to start it from another terminal?

Comment: @edwinksl Sincerely, I'm lazy to type password everytime I use `sudo` command.

Comment: @PKM You can just tell `sudo` to use the `NOPASSWD` setting (as it says — no password asked) as a safer method than a permanent root shell.

Comment: @PKM That is not recommended though; see http://askubuntu.com/questions/135428/what-are-the-benefits-of-sudo-over-su for example. Nonetheless, I cannot stop you from doing it if you insist.

Comment: @anonymous2 No, I want it to automatically run as root when I click on its icon

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I tried do it, but I don't know what to edit in `etc/sudoers`. And if set `sudo` to `NOPASSWD`, will it completely disable password for `sudo`, or just for chosen applications?

Comment: @edwinksl I know that it can be unsafe, but I'm really sick of writing my long-long password everytime :(

Comment: @PKM You can choose. Go [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password) to disable asking for all programs or [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) to disable for chosen ones.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju That is what I needed, I think now I can somehow manage to set Terminator to run in root. Thanks!

Comment: @PKM Alternatively, don't start Terminator as root, but you you can still run `sudo <some command>` without being asked for a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` (or just add it to desktop and then create a copy) so that you don't have to edit all from the start and then:

1. **First option**

   Change the `Exec=` line to:

   ```
   Exec=terminator -e "sudo -i"
   ```

   This will ask for your password when you open terminator.
2. **Second option**

   Install `gksu` (`sudo apt-get install gksu`) and change the `Exec=` line to:

   ```
   Exec=gksu terminator
   ```

   This will open a pop up which will ask you your password and give you a root terminator without any user preferences though.

*NOTE: Never run `sudo terminator` because it might change the user folder ownership or cause other problems, always use `gksu` for gui applications.*