# Edit crontab with an editor other than the default

Tags: cron, vim, nano, vi

I would like to edit crontab with vi **once**.  My default editor is nano, and I want to keep it that way.  I only want to edit with vi one time.  I don't want to change the default to vi then back to nano after editing.  Can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/55022/changing-default-crontab-editor

Answer (score 28):

`crontab` should respect the `EDITOR` environment variable, so you can just do (for the root crontab for example)

```
sudo EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

From `man crontab`

```
The -e option is used to edit the  current  crontab  using  the  editor
specified  by  the  VISUAL  or EDITOR environment variables.
```

Comment: I don't think you want `sudo` here unless you want to edit really fundamental tasks. Most people run cron jobs at user-level. Also, on Mac OS X if you use sudo it gives an error. Without it it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Specifying **nano** as the editor for crontab file

```
export VISUAL=nano
```

Specifying **vim** as the editor for crontab file

```
export VISUAL=vim
```

- now, just try it: **crontab -e**