# crontab edit produces a number and does not open the editor in ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, cron

I want to add a crontab entry.
When I run the command

```
crontab -e
```

I just get a number as output! How to fix this issue?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1RId.jpg]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you edit your question and post the output of `crontab -l`?

Comment: HI, crontab -l lists the contents of crontab correctly. only the crontab -e command was not working.. i followed the steps outlined by Rovo and selected the editor.. Now its working fine..

Answer (score 2):

`crontab` gets opened with the default editor, which is saved in the `EDITOR` environment variable.

for me, this is `vim`:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
vim
```

You can run `crontab` overriding the default editor like this:

```
EDITOR=editor-of-your-choice crontab -e
```

to permanently select a default editor, you can simply run this and choose the right number:

```
select-editor
```

then, `crontab -e` should now open with your editor of choice.

See this related question: [Changing default crontab editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55022/changing-default-crontab-editor)

Comment: In particular, the number followed by an apparently empty prompt is the behavior expected when `EDITOR=ed` (`969` being the number of lines in the file)

Comment: select-editor command did the trick.. thank you verymuch.